# How to manage and maintain product software versions on client environment?

Tags: deployment, version, product

We have a micro-services architecture product that is running on Kubernetes. We have almost 50 services with individual docker tags. We have to deploy product to multiple clients with different product versions.

To keep track of every version, patches, and tags becoming very difficult.
Can anybody suggest how people are managing it now a days?

Comment: We built Reliza Hub to solve this task - does automated versioning and bundling and sorts out requirements per client - you can find me at devopscommunity.org Discord to chat more about specific use case.